# Rails getting access to current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to save in `Note` which `Employee` was the last editor of a `Note'

In a View, I'm able to access the current employee like this:

```
<h4><%= current_user.employee.id%></h4>
```

But, in a Model, I can't use `current_user.employee.id`.

So, I'm trying this in the User model:

```
 def self.current
   Thread.current[:user]
 end
 def self.current=(user)
  Thread.current[:user] = user
 end
```

And this in the Note model:

```
before_create :record_update
before_update :record_update

protected
def record_update
  self.lasteditor_id = User.current.employee.id unless User.current.employee.id.nil?
end
```

What I'm getting is the last `User` in the `Users` table.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I created a gem awhile back to log updater and creator on any ActiveRecord objects - https://github.com/house9/clerk - not sure if it would be useful in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_user` gets the logged in user information from the session. You cannot access session variables from model. If you want to update the Note model with the Last employee who viewed it, do it in your controller(most likely show action of your note or any other action you think would be right)

```
def show
  @note = Note.find(params[:id])
  @note.update_atribute(:last_viewed_by, current_user.id)
end
```

You code might look different from above. But this is the idea